# JSON from Newtonsoft to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

So, I have a some json data which I create in my controller like so:

```
Notes = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contact.Notes.OrderBy(x => x.DateLogged).Select(x => new 
            {
                id = x.Id,
                date = x.DateLogged,
                content = x.Content,
                logged = x.Username
            }))
```

This then gets passed to the view, now which statment can I do to achieve the results of having a variable contain that json data:

```
var data = '@Html.Raw(Model.Notes)'
```

or

```
var data = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Model.Notes)');
```

---

**EDIT**

the `content` variable holds some "\n" which when passed to the view using the first choice from above generates an error, saying

> Unexpected Token

it only does it with `\n` so what is going wrong here? the bottom method doesn't quite work.

Comment: Read the generated source.

Comment: Try one and see if it works...?

Comment: I always do @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Notes)) in the View and send an object from the controller

Comment: it seems the javascript `JSON` library doesn't like `\n`, if i got with the top method with no parse then it works fine

Comment: No, the generated source probably ends up looking like `var data = '...<newline>...` and the Javascript parser itself is the one complaining about that newline.  You need to escape it somehow.  I assume @Html.Raw is meant to be put inside of HTML, not inside of a `<script>` tag.

Comment: no its not javascript parser, when I remove `JSON.parse` it works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bobince is obviously correct in what he says, it makes so much sense, thanks for that.

However, my solution was to simply do:

```
var data = @Html.Raw(Model.Notes);
```

Because, Newtonsoft already has converted it to a proper JSON format, so all it needs to do, is be assigned to a variable to be manipulated.

I think grabbing the content from a the HTML DOM is a bit too much for this.

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Model.Notes)');
```

This doesn't work - you can't put a JSON literal inside a JavaScript string. Any backslash in it will be an escape character to the JavaScript parser, not the JSON parser. A newline comes out like:

```
var data = JSON.parse('{"content": "abc\ndef"}');
```

which means the string you are asking JSON to parse is:

```
{"content": "abc

def"}
```

which is not valid as you can't have a literal newline in a JSON string.

To do this with `JSON.parse` you would have to JS-string-literal encode the JSON output, so you would end up with `"abc\\ndef"`. The alternative would be to include the JSON directly in the script block as `var data = @Html.Raw(Model.Notes);`, but there are problems with this to do with the differences between JS and JSON (primarily characters U+2028 and U+2029) and the enclosing HTML context (ie what the sequence `</script` does).

Getting the escaping right here is harder than it looks, so you should avoid injecting anything into a `<script>` block. Better to put in-page JSON data in a `data-` attribute and read it from the DOM; this way you can use the normal HTML escaping Razor gives you by default.

```
<div id="notes" data-notes="@Model.Notes">

...

var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('notes').getAttribute('data-notes'));
```